# Androids failed linking file resources with databinding

Tags: android

I am getting `error: failed linking file resources` because my deleted resource `@dimen/login_margin_top` cannot be resolved. It was used in data binding layout, that I also removed. I've tried removing all generated files, clean project, invalidate cash and restart, ./gradlew clean, and nothing works. Please help.

Comment: Can you share your full  error and layout file

Answer (score 0):

If you are making deletions then consider reverting in the following way:

1. Go to the [VCS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3FUR.png) menu in android studio
2. Click on Local history
3. Then click on show history

Then you will see the changes you made to your project over the different timestamps

In this way you can revert the files in your project to any particular timestamp so that the deletion is handled safely.

Also you can enjoy the benefits of android studio's [safe delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26274530/12980866) feature!!

Comment: `@dimen/login_margin_top` was used only in the removed layout. So I don't think so if this value is the problem. The problem is this removed layout, but the only references to it occur in generated files. I've tried to remove them and invalidate cache, so it is strange, that in newly generated classes, still occurs reference to this layout. Do You know, what can case the problem? Maybe strange way of caching layouts, that I do not understand?